# Thredds getCapabilities for ncWMS server

Tags: netcdf, wms, unidata, thredds, ncwms1.2

Thredds Data Server TDS provides getCapabilities for a netCDF file. 
e.g. [http://localhost:8080/thredds/wms/testAll/Filename.nc?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities](http://localhost:8080/thredds/wms/testAll/%3CFilename.nc%3E?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities)
Here, the filename would be a netCDF dataset present at this location in tomcat.

*tomcat/content/thredds/public/testdata*

Is there a way where I can display all layers getCapabilities document like it is explicitly available by ncWMS server.
eg. http://localhost:8080/ncWMS2/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each dataset on THREDDS has a separate WMS endpoint with separate `getCapabilities` response.

So if you wanted to get all the WMS layers from all the datasets on a THREDDS server, you would need to crawl the THREDDS catalog, retrieving all the WMS endpoints, and then query each WMS endpoint individually with `GetCapabilities` to get all the layers (variables) for each dataset.